# Which question was this, about integration and the $\pi=4$ paradox?

Tags: support, specific-question

There was a question here about how one can justify that integration does indeed give the area under a curve. Specifically, the OP brought up [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZrY8.png) image. The OP was troubled that even though Riemann sums intuitively "should" give the area, staircase approximation like in that image "should" give the length, so they doubted their intuition.

I found a few questions that used that image, but none of them were the one I wanted, which was specifically about Riemann integration. I don't think the question title even mentioned pi = 4, it was framed as a question about integration.

These aren't it:

- [contradicting PI=4 fallacy.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123540/contradicting-pi-4-fallacy?lq=1)
- [How to convince a layman that the $\pi = 4$ proof is wrong?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43118/how-to-convince-a-layman-that-the-pi-4-proof-is-wrong)
- [Is value of $\pi = 4$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/is-value-of-pi-4?lq=1)

Comment: This question would be a lot better if you **gave a list** of all the questions you found and ruled out...

Comment: Is it this: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/43118/264 ?

Comment: @ZevChonoles No, and I've included a list as you suggested.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you  want to look up back at that question since it was posted 6 months ago?

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع I was curious what the answers said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting [your picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZrY8.png) into Google Images "search by image" and restricting the search to [site:math.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?safe=off&tbs=sbi%3AAMhZZisyXg0a3uv_1mO2QnUqcb3NXh4Sd-6AeM6eueOf3HZP5i4PoeEbMxmog_1gS-yZBDRBz1aygG-G-wDafSiEZ55lVSG-cqoDue01aHKwBtCvNm_1QnmQwnw39QKd7qzy4-HxPLIni3uRk8kCYhbLIJxxB06qWdVzJfm4cYoC4B5huyAlZuP2OFD1of18SkW6B-CBQfNTzpXKb6k45w7iexJ55Ld4Rt8odqzEDl2XMTmSgD4gCaJ0sU4HuXTa_1TzcSwgtaVIiKwtp3EMnnzfSo-RlKwKogR4B-tJppXjxAnUS23i1PuTklnQH-xccG4IeAEMs6YyptSa0Kf9B-AsD8L3xMHpgWhk3EZkSVc7GCVPJvUJh5p1tb-s1ATXn3xoxLehmETibLB8cSuXh2XD3-DxE8zHKD3XlpbeCdWoaJP-vk8j9qiz_1jT1W6OUgxCnhpe94yLw9X8QckBft1OFM2fDeG7p7m2aAi4_1cMfJ4mT-qM_1rjjZtdIi8chp1kgRUCqgPPBXaZ1HMhTUBdLMI_1KDviH1ISUBASvus_1PeOwu52pNkjKq8GNGpBhe5M1Iiy66z4YAaKzSqHCsB88Q_1YCESZV_1E9XU7uK0Ofz_16r9kgEC-5DaVekll4H-g2CIzVApJ8qETfjq9Fd3L3bI3vtPmHQjli1I2flSmaVHS9yxiVlLr_1QnKYgiPh6g4BEVd3E-RLuZDrgiPmUA1pckUDsdHrXrhqqPyKvoFhXFBp8LEJIwhP_12sxVvmcV0K6IJZuMJNquciEqowPI00I9JnRGU0Mcxk2v-qxQgr2vCiA43RmmksjaRx5mMVr314rNWu2iyZkjUAtfeDFC8_1uD1i1gOmvGqkn-znQUkRt_1lo2ZRklK4YPG2k99qFBCiVvc8UGmxSylHZe_1iBFcQLStrmiFI7hVbCrVRPRI4u9CQj8VRAJuKrI1vcGwiaFfM9zKCMrW0e8C5vZkE6_1pRN_17q8_1cG5x4vCfn2nI5r_1M_1I0eWRinGS2bRwRF8NWsvqpJMq57gl4zVLzvnpXEg93Nsj3UyyMVI-zoKke7OZrj7JiXnsFQnXpBgZdUl5zhiBsC4XCdsc3-xzukO846RBlw0S2PHJ9NeyS3YceZJLWj3L-L_1lMg1TUO-V0oiiPBSK8frjHBIQMfr1HzBeBxdP3p16eoTWIfi-UGhPiwvwcqX3eyftUQVAHd4_1RbMA6UCFl0VM_1vVqKxKzGisS9oJTrYS4D_184zo9H5VVeXHLP5k2he8GZYA6AqHVGOSUhYmRMo8gswOgeIhUj9MaaliO_1CTet_1jCpuGcbGjUCoC4fiVXShK7XkUlryXCqxDYssDz60faB9bDXMgMtlABK4P2nUW5hOxkZkS60ChWZPkBrRIkZUtT6FvDQLgMNM-gPcCtiiPvbFitLowrwRKmMSb3rMyqCqVoAMfmrDV5ec5tm0kqxJpe0Fpyyf6Wx7WvZ5k&q=site%3Amath.stackexchange.com&oq=site%3Amath.stackexchange.com&gs_l=serp.3...5185.22727.0.23034.34.31.2.0.0.0.166.2716.21j10.31.0....0...1c.1.35.serp..24.10.824.hCesKxoPtJ4) returns these four questions:

- [Is value of $\pi = 4$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/is-value-of-pi-4)
- [Approximating an integral with rectangles? Legal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536124/approximating-an-integral-with-rectangles-legal)
- [Two paradoxes: $\pi = 2$ and $\sqrt 2 = 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229263/two-paradoxes-pi-2-and-sqrt-2-2)
- [How to find the area. Linked with another question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133197/how-to-find-the-area-linked-with-another-question)

Based on further details provided in your post, you probably meant: [Approximating an integral with rectangles? Legal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536124/approximating-an-integral-with-rectangles-legal)

Comment: That was the first trick I tried, but I didn't find that last one, which is indeed the one I wanted. Thanks.